# Running parallel Selenium tests on several Virtual Machines using Grid/Node

Tags: java, selenium, ant, junit, parallel-processing

I have a problem with **Selenium tests** running **simultaneously** on **several Virtual Machines**.

The first VM I have is a ubuntu server to run tests on nodes. The second one is Win7 (for IE9) and last one with Win7 (for Firefox). I have successfuly configured the hub and the nodes using selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar.

I was also able to run tests from ANT and it works really well. With my ubuntu server, I am deciding what node is capable to run test and run it.

**My problem is that I cannot run the tests in parallel.**

For example:

I have 4 tests - 2 for firefox and 2 for internet explorer.
With the Ubuntu server I start first test on VM1 and wait for it to end. Then I start the second test on VM2 and wait for it to end. Then test 3 and test 4.

It takes a lot of time, when it could be run simultaneously. My question is: **how?** I want to run tests on VM1 and VM2 parallely and when the tests on VM1 on VM2 ends, the next tests are immediately started on the idle VMs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**TestNG**](http://testng.org) to run the test in parallel.
[**This**](https://saucelabs.com/java/se2/8) might help

Comment: Well, i can't use TestNG, i have to use JUnit4.